# Encountered " "MERGE" "MERGE "" at line 1, column 1. Was expecting: <EOF>

Tags: google-bigquery, legacy-sql

We must need to use Legacy SQL in BigQuery. But, Merge is not working in Legacy SQL. How we write below query in Legacy SQL?

```
MERGE [ABC:xyz.tmp_cards] AS target_tbl 
USING [ABC:xyz.tmp_cards_1533188902] AS source_tbl 
ON target_tbl.id = source_tbl.id
WHEN MATCHED AND target_tbl.id = source_tbl.id THEN
   UPDATE SET target_tbl.id = source_tbl.id,
   target_tbl.user_id = source_tbl.user_id,
   target_tbl.expiration_date = source_tbl.expiration_date,
   target_tbl.created_at = source_tbl.created_at,
   target_tbl.updated_at = source_tbl.updated_at 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
   INSERT (id, user_id, expiration_date, created_at, updated_at) 
   VALUES (source_tbl.id, source_tbl.user_id, source_tbl.expiration_date, source_tbl.created_at, source_tbl.updated_at)
```

Comment: MERGE does not work with legacy, that's a correct fact.

Comment: What is the solution for the same? Can you please provide me query which will work without merge?

Comment: Why do you need to use legacy SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for DML MERGE statements [appeared in Beta just this year for standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#april_10_2018). It's not possible to do it in Legacy SQL and this is why [Standard SQL is the preferred SQL dialect](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql) for querying data stored in BigQuery. Because the new features are for the last DML for BigQuery and not the old one.